# Python split lists

Tags: python, string, list

I try to split a list at a specific character. My code I tried:

```
lol = ['lol&sa=asddaa', 'test&sa=asd', 'well&sa=123123']
test = "\n".join(lol)

for x in test:
    print test.split("&sa")[0]
```

But this isn't working. I just get "lol" like a hundred time as output. What could be the solution?

The output I want:

```
lol
test
well
```

so that it splits at "&sa"

Comment: `for x` is looping through every character in test. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: @Keatinge What should I do otherwise?

Comment: provide a [mcve] and show us what your output should be

Comment: @Lucas what you should do depends on the output you want, post the output you are expecting in the question

Comment: How should we know? You haven't specified anything. People cannot read your mind.

Comment: @Keatinge im sry.. that was pretty dumb I have to say. Sry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you meant:

```
for x in lol:
    print x.split("&sa")[0]
```

It outputs:

```
lol
test
well
```